# Failed to render and update auto layout status Stripe.Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

I do not know what is going on, but all of a sudden my xcode stopped rendering autolayouts [image]

Here is a picture of the errors i am getting from xcode.

Edit:

The solution for me was to run the command

```
pod install
```

Comment: same issue any solution ?

Comment: This seems to be due to a [bug](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/7606) in CocoaPods. Until it's fixed, the best options are the workaround from @HarshilKotecha's answer, or to downgrade to an older version of CocoaPods(apparently v1.4.0 should work).

Answer (score 1):

This is work for me

https://github.com/evgenyneu/Cosmos/issues/105

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'XYZ' do

use_frameworks!

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED')
        config.build_settings.delete('CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED')
    end
end

pod 'Alamofire'
pod 'Stripe'
/* etc ... */
  # Uncomment the next line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Gozem Provider
end
```

after u can install or update pod

------------------------------ OR --------------------------------------

If your project select automatically manage signing than remove it

[image]

make it like u can select None otherwise you can use ur currect certificate  than clean project and build again

[image]

Comment: I forwarded this to the stripe team.  I hope they fix their pod so that we dont have to do this workaround.